# upgrade bcb6 app to newer version

Tags: c++builder, vcl

Is the latest VCL similar to 6.0? I use Borland Builder 6. I know at first they dropped vcl.. but it seems like they came back to it? My app is 15 years old and maybe 300 forms, so a major rewrite isn't an option for now... lot of code tied too tightly to UI also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VCL has never been dropped in any version of Delphi; C++BuilderX, mentioned by Remy in the comment below (which was a very short-lived and forgettable product) dropped it for it's very short lifespan.

The VCL is being supplemented now by (and will maybe be replaced by in the future) FireMonkey, which is cross-platform. It was supplemented once (in Delphi 6) by CLX, the QT-based cross-platform library for Kylix, but Delphi 6 included both it and the VCL.

Your app will probably work fine in newer versions of C++Builder as long as it doesn't do anything that assumes a certain size for `char` values. Delphi and Builder since 2009 have been Unicode instead of Ansi, so the default string type changed from `AnsiString` to `UnicodeString`, and the character type went from `AnsiChar` to `WideChar`.

(Also, I removed the `borland` tag, as Borland hasn't been associated with either C++Builder or Delphi for a few years now. Both products are now owned by [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com) instead.)

Comment: After BCB6, C++Builder itself was indeed dropped for awhile, replaced with C++BuilderX (which was a cross-platform IDE with no VCL), then CBX was dropped and the original C++Builder was picked back up and updated to match Delphi 2007, and has continued on ever since.

Comment: Ok. Forgot about the 10 minutes there was a C++BuilderX. Or was it 15? ;) I'll edit that out, though, since you feel it was important enough to reminisce about. <g> Was there something wrong with the rest of the answer?

Comment: VCL is not likely to ever be replaced with FireMonkey. They are very different frameworks for different purposes. VCL is intimately tied to Windows and that will not change. Legacy code will port to newer versions of VCL just fine. CLX attempted to make the existing VCL be cross-platform with as little code change as possible. That failed. FireMonkey is not taking that approach. It is a new framework designed from scratch. It has a few similarities to VCL, but that is all.

Comment: Perhaps you have inside information the rest of us don't, but it's been mentioned in the EMBT forums that anyone wanting to write Xplat apps will need to switch to FM. I'd suspect, with the mobile and other support becoming more and more necessary, many people will make the transition. If the VCL becomes the minority player in the UI, and the VCL isn't worth the maintenance effort any longer, it will go away. Already, there are minimal improvements in the VCL while all is concentrated on FM. But you're right. I should probably edit to say "possibly" instead of "probably".

Comment: C++BuilderX, that's the name of the product that made me drop all hopes for VCL/Builder.  Thanks for the info, I'll be sure to give them another look.  I have had to modify/hack at the VCL for various bugs/work-arounds, so I'm sure it would take some work to upgrade, but much easier than switching to C# .NET Winforms/WPF at least.